# How to import a function from a class without import in all class using webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm new to webpack.
I have a class A which imports a function from class B. But for some reason webpack is importing all B class instead of importing only the function foo. any idea why it's importing all B?

```
import {foo} from './B'
export default class A {
    foo();
    ...
}
```

```
export default class B {
   ...
    static foo(){
      //Do something
    }
}
export const foo = B.foo;
```

I tried

```
export default class B {
    ...
}

export function foo(){
 //Do something
}
```

Comment: I usually `export class B` and `export foo` then if I want B I `import {B} from '...'` or `import {foo} from '...'` what if you take away the `default`

Comment: thank you for the answer! taking away the default didn't solve the problem for me

Comment: so you're saying `console.log(typeof B)` is NOT 'undefined' when in module `A`? Like when using your example of "what you have tried"